# Is there an AI tool to reverse engineer scanned data to obtain its CAD file?

Tags: ai-design, image-recognition, resource-request

Today, if you scan an object and want its CAD file (Solidworks/Autocad), you need to use reverse engineering software (Geomagic). This takes time and you need experience of the software tools.

Is there an AI tool/app that does the job automatically? If not, is this a reasonable idea to develop an AI application capable of doing it? What would be the biggest challenges?

Answer (score 2):

Two years later, it seems there is no (open) project to train AI on engineering data and **no AI tool** to reverse engineer things yet.

The growing number of open source hardware projects should provide a good basic training set.. https://oho.wiki and https://certification.oshwa.org/list.html provide catalogues of specimens for example.. Realtime 3d generation should also be good enough by now to **get this going**..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).